# Synchronized getter and synchronized thread run method in java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, java-threads

The followiing code uses threads to calculate the max value in a subarry, and then calculates the max value out of the max values the threads returned. I have a bug that the main thread doesn't wait for the threads to finish when collecting the results.

Thread class:

```
public class MaxTask extends Thread {
  private int[] arr;
  private int max;
  private int first, last;
  public MaxTask(int[] arr, int first, int last) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }
  public int getMax() {
    return max;
  }
  public void run() {
    max = arr[first];
    for (int i = first + 1; i <= last; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
public class MainMax {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int size = 100;
    int workers = 10;
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
      if (max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("max=" + max);
    int gsize = (arr.length - 1) / workers;
    MaxTask[] tasks = new MaxTask[workers];
    int first = 0;
    int last;
    for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++) {
      last = first + gsize;
      tasks[i] = new MaxTask(arr, first, last);
      tasks[i].start();
      first = last + 1;
    }
    int maxmax = tasks[0].getMax();
    int temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < workers; i++) {
      temp = tasks[i].getMax();
      if (temp > maxmax) maxmax = temp;
    }
    System.out.println("maxmax=" + maxmax);
  }
}
```

I am trying to solve the problem using `synchronized`. I managed to get it working when using `synchronized` on both `run` and `getMax`. But I really don't understand why this solves the problem.

Comment: Re, "I am trying to solve the problem using `synchronized`." That's a mistake. `synchronized` should be used for one thing only: Use it to prevent different threads from accessing the same shared data at the same time. There are numerous other ways\* to make one thread wait for another thread to _do_ something. The way to make thread A wait for thread B to _terminate_ is to have thread A call `B.join()`. \[\* See the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package for some examples.\]

Answer (score 0):

First, you must understand that the main class is also running on a thread. That thread is seperate from the threads you created for the function and is thus running in parallel to them. By that logic, `int maxmax = tasks[0].getMax();` is running asynchronously and possibly before the loop is finished.

One possible solution would be to lock that part of the code and force the execution to wait before executing that line. Only release the lock after everyone in the loop is done. Synchronizing access to the run method only defeats the purpose of running multiple threads since you're forcing the whole thing to be sequential.

It is also not recommended to create a thread for every single element, since there's a tradeoff between number of threads and how much you're speeding up execution.